# Cant Find antd css module while importing in index.css

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have installed antd dependancy while working on a react app and i am trying to import css from antd using import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
but its showing an error that :

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/dist/antd.css' in '/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/cryptoverse/src'
> ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-28
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/dist/antd.css' in '/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/cryptoverse/src'

Source Code of index.js file is this :

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';



ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
<App/>
</Router>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

My dependancies in Package.json are :

> "dependencies": {
> "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
> "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
> "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
> "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
> "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
> "antd": "^5.2.0",
> "axios": "^1.3.2",
> "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
> "html-react-parser": "^3.0.9",
> "millify": "^5.0.1",
> "moment": "^2.29.4",
> "react": "^18.2.0",
> "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
> "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
> "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
> "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
> "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
> "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

Project Structure is :
https://ibb.co/17zJkMf

I tried to Import antd/dist/antd.css and i was expecting the css styling to get applied on my Application but its not even getting imported and showing module not Found .

Answer (score 1):

I see your issue. But the problem is that, The file you need has been removed since the Version 5 of Ant Design. It was removed and a file called 'reset.css' was added. I hope this helps.

Link to see
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/CHANGELOG.en-US.md

'Remove dist/antd.css, and add dist/reset.css to override common styles.'

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` to `import './antd/dist/antd.css';`

Comment: its still not working .

Comment: please provide your screenshot of project hierarchy structure

Comment: https://ibb.co/17zJkMf

Comment: all of your files should be inside `src` folder, for development, can't import outside man.
but you can custom or put files in `public` folder.

Comment: All of them are in SRC . in public only index.html is present . https://github.com/PARASnagpal99/CryptoVerse . Github Link for further reference . Thanks sir for replying btw upto now.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://unpkg.com/browse/antd@5.2.0/dist/), this is the file structure in antd package, there is only `antd/dist/reset.css` instead of `antd/dist/antd.css`

I didn't test the code but I think it should work by changing the file name like the above.

Comment: Yes its not giving an error but styling is not getting applied like in the tutorial .

Comment: Maybe a hard refresh `Ctrl + F5` on your browser will do?